# PHP interpreter makes external js and css into html embedded codes

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, host

I have the follow external css / js file in the **index.php** file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".css/main.css" type="text/css">
<script src=".js/main.js?"></script>
```

**Problem**
When I open the page in browser, all css / js code become inline as below

```
<style>
 /* css code */
</style>
<script>
 /* jscode */
</script>
```

Someone know what "cool" php function is it? I would happy to have it disabled on the host.
please check the link http://toolkit4kinder.com/test/index.php

```
cat index.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
<body>
        <div> hello </div>
        <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you add the php code that you used!!?

Comment: I updated the question with the php code

Comment: Your need to **ask your host**.

Comment: I did asked my host. they have no clue so far.

Comment: I am checking out these feature: https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-js-inline ; https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-js-inline; if it is because of these features, do you know how to avoid them?

Comment: @QiaoLi got there in the end, well done.

Answer (score 2):

**RCA**
The inline css / js was generated by the following features on the host:

```
https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-js-inline
https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-css-inline
```

**Solution**
create / edit .htaccess in the folder with the following code to disable the feature:

```
$ cat .htaccess
ModPagespeed Off
```